# Getting coordinates of the cropped image in Cropie

Tags: javascript, crop

With Cropie, I can successfully crop uploaded image and save as base64. I know how to save base64 data as a new file on backend.

What I wonder is, is there a way to get the cropped `area (x1, y1, x2, y2)` so that I can upload the original image instead of cropped base64 and complete my cropping with imagemagick on backend.

Refering [example code here](https://codepen.io/alsmpd/pen/ZQwOQB):

```
$('#upload').on('change', function () {
    readFile(this);
});
$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'original'
    }).then(function (resp) {
        $('#imagebase64').val(resp);
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
croppieDemo.croppie('get');
```

will give you points to crop

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and moved to Cropper. The answer is Croppie is the not the right tool for this.